# Example in np.argsort document

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

For some reason I cannot resolve this.

According to the example here for 1-dim array,
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

```
x = np.array([3, 1, 2])
np.argsort(x)
```

> array([1, 2, 0])

And I have tried this myself. But by default, the return result should be ascending..meaning

```
x([result])
```

returns

> array([1, 2, 3])

Thus shouldnt the result be [2,0,1]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, the first line states "Returns the indices that would sort an array." Hence if you want the positions of the sorted values we have:

```
x = np.array([3, 1, 2])
np.argsort(x)
>>>array([1, 2, 0])
```

here we want the index positions of 1, 2 and 3 in x. The psotion of 3 is 0, the psotion of 1 is 1, and the position of 2 is 2, hence `array([1, 2, 0])` = sorted_array(1,2,3).

Again from the notes, " argsort returns an array of indices of the same shape as a that index data along the given axis in sorted order."

A more intuitive way of looking at what that means is to use a for loop, where we loop over our returned `argsort` values, and then index the initial array with these values:

```
x   = np.array([3, 1, 2])
srt_positions = np.argsort(x)

for k in srt_positions:
    print x[k]

>>> 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: I came across this while transferring codes from matlab to python. The index that matlab returns I guess is only indicative

Comment: No worries. If you are just looking for a sorted array you would probably be better served using plain `sort`. I.e. `sorted(x, reverse= False )`